# Redis Master-Slave replication: can I write on a slave and have it replicated?

Tags: redis, master-slave

This is a bit of an odd question, but either the way to do it is buried deep in the web, or it is just stupid.

I have a master instance of Redis on a server (s1) and a slave instance on another server (s2). I have a parallel computation going on in both the servers and I would like to have them to be able to read and write on their instance of Redis and be able to read what has been written from the other party (and possibly write on top of it).

I know that writing on the master from s1 will cause s2 to be able to read the changes, but writing from s2 on the slave doesn't update the master. Is there a way, or a workaround, to do this? I would like to avoid having s2 connected directly to the master in s1 for performance reasons.

Thanks

Comment: The scenario that you are describing is more commonly referred to as Master-Master replication, which atm Redis doesn't do.